# convert chunks of numpy array to tuple

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array like this

```
array([[243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [245],
       [244],
       [244],
       [244],
       [243],
```

and every three element from it will be converted into a tuple! I have written a simple generator like this,

```
def RGBchunks(a_list):
    for i in range(0,len(a_list),3):
        temp = []
        for j in range(3):
            temp.extend(a_list[i+j])
        yield tuple(temp)
```

Which gives what I wanted, like this,

```
>>> for i in RGBchunks(my_arr):
         print(i)


(243, 243, 243)
(243, 243, 243)
(243, 243, 243)
(244, 244, 244)
(245, 245, 245)
(244, ........
..............
(243, 243, 243)
```

I'm curious as to know whether is there some simple elegant way to do this in numpy! And probably all those tuples in a new list? any Pythonic way is I'm curious. performance increasing would be very good too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simple reshape operation without any overlaps, use `reshape`:

```
my_arr.reshape(-1, 3)
```

Or,

```
np.reshape(my_arr, (-1, 3))
```

```
array([[243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 243],
       [243, 245, 244],
       [244, 244, 243]])
```

If you really want a list of tuples, call `map` on the reshaped result:

```
list(map(tuple, my_arr.reshape(-1, 3)))
```

Or, with a list comprehension for performance:

```
[tuple(x) for x in my_arr.reshape(-1, 3)]
```

```
[(243, 243, 243), (243, 243, 243), (243, 245, 244), (244, 244, 243)]
```

---

For overlapping strides, there's `stride_tricks`:

```
f = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
n = 3

f(my_arr, shape=(my_arr.shape[0] - (n + 1), n), strides=my_arr.strides)

array([[243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 243],
       [243, 243, 245],
       [243, 245, 244],
       [245, 244, 244],
       [244, 244, 244],
       [244, 244, 243]])
```

Comment: i'm your fan coldspeed good answers u give... can you tell me using that `list(map())` will it be good in terms of performance? worried about time a alot! any other way or??

Comment: @poda_badu If a list of tuples is what you need, then you will need to iterate. `map` hides the loop at the cost of performance. You can explore the use of a list comprehension which is slightly faster. Also, thanks for the complement, much appreciated :)

Comment: sorry to bother what exactly is that `-1` in reshape mean, 3 means three columns but -1? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @void when you're too lazy to calculate the dimension, you can ask numpy to infer it for you. You'll need to specify N-1 dimensions if you want it to infer the Nth dimension.